# Find the location of a directory at runtime to provide a default directory

Tags: vimscript, plugin-system

I want to move some scripts that I have made to some sort of standalone plugin. The content would look like

```
myplug/
  plugin/
  mydefaultdir/
```

For the scripts, I require a set of files which could have any name. Those are located in `mydefaultdir/`. I have a function that list the content of that directory and helps use it in the ensuing script. However, I want to leave to the user the option to select an entirely different directory than the one I am providing. For that I can use

```
:let g:scriptdir = get(g:, 'scriptdir', "/path/to/plug/mydefaultdir")
:call myfunc(g:scriptdir)
```

However, I cannot be sure where my plugin is located, and hence cannot set the `/path/to/plug` fixed.

I suppose I could look to `rtp`, but even that would fail if the user decided to rename the plugin directory.

I am assuming that there are better ways to do that (using runtimepath/runtime?). But essentially; it boils down to...

**How can a plugin find where it is itself located?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can a plugin find where it is itself located?

You need to `expand()` `<sfile>`. Assuming your code resides in `myplug/plugin/<somefile.vim>`:

```
# the first :h is to skip the script name;
# the second is to skip "plugin/" part
let s:mydefaultdir = expand("<sfile>:h:h") . "/mydefaultdir"
...
let g:scriptdir = get(g:, 'scriptdir', s:mydefaultdir)
```